# Show that the trace bilinear form is nondegenerate

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, bilinear-form

Consider a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ which contains a subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and its nontrivial irreducible representation $\pi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathrm{End}(V)$. I've shown that $\pi$ is faithful. Now I'm trying to prove that the trace bilinear form $B_V$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ by $B(X,Y)=\mathrm{tr}(\pi(X)\pi(Y))$ is nondegenerate, that is, $B(X,Y)=0$ for all $Y\in\mathfrak{g}$ implies $X=0$.

I suppose one can immediately conclude that it is nondegenerate if $B_V$ is nonzero, but how to elaborate it?

Comment: Do you know that $B(X,Y)$ restricted to a subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ must be non-zero?  Because I can show you how to reduce the problem to $\mathfrak{h}$, but if you don't know that $B$ cannot be zero on $\mathfrak{h}$, proving it requires some heavier machinary beyond the level of the question.

Comment: I don’t know that fact. I’d be appreciative if you can introduce and explain the “heavier machinery” to illuminate it!@Chad K

Comment: That's too much to ask.  I suggest you read Humphreys' Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory in an orderly fashion.  After reading 25-30 pages you'll understand the answer to the problem.

Comment: The details in my question seem a little bit different from the book that you recommended me to read, but I suppose I got it. Could you help me check my answer below? @Chad K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $S:=\{X\in\mathfrak{g}\mid B(X,Y)=0,\ \forall Y\in\mathfrak{g}\}$. Let $X\in S$ and $Z\in\mathfrak{g}$. We claim that $B([X,Z],Y)=B(X,[Z,Y])$ and it immediately follows that $B([X,Z],Y)=0$. To verify it, write $[\pi(X),\pi(Z)]\pi(Y)=\pi(X)\pi(Z)\pi(Y)-\pi(Z)\pi(X)\pi(Y)$, $\pi(X)[\pi(Z),\pi(Y)]=\pi(X)\pi(Z)\pi(Y)-\pi(X)\pi(Y)\pi(Z)$, and apply the fact that $\mathrm{tr}(\pi(Z)\pi(X)\pi(Y))=\mathrm{tr}(\pi(X)\pi(Y)\pi(Z))$. Hence $[X,Z]\in S$, i.e., $S$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$.

We conclude that $\pi(S)\cong S$ since $\pi$ is faithful. It follows from Cartan's criterion (see Theorem 4.3 in *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory* by Humphreys) that $S$ is solvable, i.e., $\pi(S)$ is solvable. Since $\pi$ is irreducible and $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple, $S\cong\pi(S)=0$. Thus, $B_V$ is nondegenerate.

Comment: Sounds good, except $S$ as you defined it apriori is a linear sub-space of $\mathfrak{g}$.  You need to prove that $S$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$.  For this you first show that $B([x,y],z)=B(x,[y,z])$ for all $x,y,z\in\mathfrak{g}$ (this is called an invariant form), and from this identity it is straightforward to show that $S$ is an ideal.  Since it's a solvable ideal as you proved, and $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple, $S$ has to be zero.